# I Keep Getting the Message 'System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call koneksi()
    If Label22.Text >= 5 Or Val(Label11.Text) + Val(TextBox1.Text) > 5 Then
        MsgBox("Buku yang di pinjam melebihi MAKSIMAL")
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {ComboBox2.Text, Label16.Text, Label17.Text, Label18.Text, TextBox1.Text})
        Call rumusBuku()
    End If
End Sub
```

What should I do if it keeps giving the message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: Presumably one of the `Val()` operations is producing that error?  The error is telling you exactly what's wrong.  An empty string can't be converted to a `Double`.  What `Double` value are you expecting an empty string to become and why?

Comment: The message is literally telling you, that you are trying to convert a string to type double and it is invalid...

Comment: You may want to consider using `Double.TryParse` instead of `Val`.  I'd recommend against ever using `Val`, it's a compatibility function to support upgrading code from the VBA-heritage versions of VB (up to and including VB6) and may have unexpected behavior for some inputs.

Comment: Also, `Call` in `Call rumusBuku()`, is unnecessary in VB.NET.